# Почему при выводе строк на экран, вместе с ними печатается "мусор"?

Tags: c++, стек

Здравствуйте. Выполняю очередное задание из книжки по С++. Сделал простенький статический стек, написал для работы с ним несколько функций. Когда вывожу на экран его содержимое(строки) получаю дополнительно куски "мусора" после каждого слова.

Объясните пожалуйста в чем тут дело?

Код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct str_stack
{
    char mas[10][100];
    int top;
};

void init_stack(str_stack &s);
void push_stack(str_stack &s,char st[]);
char* pop_stack(str_stack &s);
void print_stack(str_stack &s);

int main()
{
    str_stack ss;
    char str[100];
    init_stack(ss);
    cout << "\n***Simple stack***\n";
    do
    {
        cout<<"Input string in stack: ";
        cin>>str;
        push_stack(ss,str);
    }while(str[0]!='*');
    print_stack(ss);
    return 0;
}
void init_stack(str_stack &s)
{
    s.top=0;
}
void push_stack(str_stack &s,char st[])
{
    int i=0;
    while(st[i]!='\0'&&i<100)
    {
        s.mas[s.top][i]=st[i];
        i++;
    }
    s.top++;
}
void print_stack(str_stack &s)
{
    int i;
    char *ch;
    cout<<"\n";
    while(s.top>0)
    {
        i=0;
        ch=pop_stack(s);
        while(ch[i]!='\0')
        {
            cout<<ch[i];
            i++;
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
}
char* pop_stack(str_stack &s)
{
    return s.mas[--s.top];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А кто будет ноль в самом конце дописывать? (метод push_stack)
Можно конечно так написать

```
while(st[i]!='\0'&&i<100)
    {
        s.mas[s.top][i]=st[i];
        i++;
    }
s.mas[s.top][i] = '\0';
```

а можно узнать о функции strcpy и радоваться жизни (она копирует хитрее и часто в несколько раз быстрее, чем обычный цикл).

Comment: Ох, спасибо вам и за функцию о которой я позабыл и за разъяснение.